# NSURLSession not using cached responses

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I am able to see cached responses when I query `NSURLCache` directly but when I request the same resource through `NSURLSession:dataTaskWithRequest` it always queries the server and never gives me the cached response, even with internet disabled.

I configure `NSURLCache` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
                          diskCapacity: 80 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

Then I am using this code to check the cache and fetch the response:

```
print("cached response is \(NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)?.response)")

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
  print("nsurlsession response \(response)")
}.resume()
```

The result of my debug prints are:

```
cached response is Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f809d0ddfe0> { URL: https://api.test.com/stuff } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "public, s-maxage=600";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Tue, 06 Sep 2016 23:41:24 GMT";
Etag = "\"4800a836fee27c56a3cce1f0f2bddaefa5a7785b\"";
Server = "nginx/1.11.3";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-RateLimit-Limit" = 60;
"X-RateLimit-Remaining" = 2; } })

nsurlsession response Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f809d202e50> { URL: https://api.test.com/stuff } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "public, s-maxage=600";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Tue, 06 Sep 2016 23:51:52 GMT";
Etag = "\"4800a836fee27c56a3cce1f0f2bddaefa5a7785b\"";
Server = "nginx/1.11.3";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-RateLimit-Limit" = 60;
"X-RateLimit-Remaining" = 52; } })
```

As you can see, the Cache-Control headers from the server are set to allow caching. I am not doing anything special with my request, just creating a default `NSURLRequest` with a URL. Each time I trigger the request, the new response gets cached, but it is never retrieved on subsequent requests.

Is there any reason why `NSURLSession` would not use a response stored in `NSURLCache`? Is there something I must do to tell `NSURLSession` to actually look up requests in the cache?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't tell you with absolute certainty why the cache isn't being consulted, but I can give you a list of the most likely reasons:

- The server did not respond with 304 when queried about the validity of that ETag header (IIRC using a HEAD request).
- The request is too big—either relative to the size of the buffer or in absolute terms.  The cache should at least be a couple of orders of magnitude bigger than the requests that you would typically cache; anything over about 5% of the cache size will not be cached.
- The request method is something other than GET.  (Only GET requests are cached unless you monkey with the machinery significantly.)
- More than 10 minutes have elapsed (600 seconds isn't very long).
- The request was made in a different URL session that has a different backing cache.
- The request was made in an ephemeral URL session or a session that for some other reason has no cache.
- The session actually is returning the cached response, but you're seeing a request because it is revalidating a little more aggressively than you might expect—possibly because it will reach its maximum age so soon.
- Your URL request is getting handled in the background by a custom NSURLProtocol that doesn't respect the cache (e.g. because of some badly behaved third-party networking or advertising framework).
- The request had not actually been fully written to the cache when you tried to retrieve it (timing race caused by multiple threads).

I'm probably forgetting several others.  With that said, if I'm forgetting them, that probably means that they aren't documented.

So...

If you verify that everything listed above is working as expected, file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com and include enough code to reproduce the problem, along with a packet dump if possible.

Comment: Thank you, that was *extremely* helpful. As a front-end engineer it is very difficult for me to figure out all the places where a network issue could be happening. I tried hitting a TVDB url to eliminate issues with the client's configuration, and caching works for that, so I suspect the issue is with the ETag revalidation.

Comment: Turned out the server was not sending 304s during ETag validation. Verified with Charles proxy and got it fixed. I hadn't realized that the client would attempt validation before the response had become stale.

Comment: Neat.  Glad that helped.

Comment: Is it possible to debug (e.g. print) to see whether or not cached data was used for a certain datatask (without having to use tools like Charles/Wireshark)?

Comment: If the headers from the server contain a timestamp, you could presumably decode that on the client side and know when the response was originally sent.  Or you could *maybe* provide your own cache class that wraps NSURLCache and adds extra logging.  Not sure if there are other ways.